Documentary: Man climbing big tree with rope to get honey
I remember watching a documentary about 10 years ago in a culture anthropology course where a man gets rope around a tree and then starts climbing it (huge, like as tall as Sequoia) and as he's climbing he has a little axe where he chops a little area for his feet to stay and then moves up a bit. He does this until he gets all the way up and gets the honey.
I remember it also had really nice music playing, I think it was a kid playing it on a 4 string instrument.
I believe the documentary was in English, about an African tribe, and I don't remember how long it was, perhaps an hour.

I believe you are looking for the 1988 National Geographic - Baka, People of the Trees. The Baka are a nomadic tribe in Cameroon, they are a tribe of pygmies who value sugar so highly, that they will scale very large trees in search of honey from the hives that the top.
The BBC also aired one in 2011 about this - Human Planet - People of the Trees Given the similarity in the names, it may be the same documentary, I was unable to view footage to confirm.
The trees are not as tall as Sequioas, but given that it's a pygmy climbing, that may have skewed the perception.
